# How to loop over each element of a list with another element of another list in R

Tags: r, list, loops, combinations

I have to 2 list such as follow:

```
List1 <- c("X", "Y","Z")
List2 <- c("Enable", "Status", "Quality")
```

I am expecting something like this:

```
X_Enable, X_Status,X_Quality,Y_Enable, Y_Status,Y_Quality, Z_Enable, Z_Status,Z_Quality.
```

Any recommendation will be helpful for me.Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Here a way to do it:

### Data

```
List1 <- c("X", "Y","Z")
List2 <- c("Enable", "Status", "Quality")
```

### Code

```
paste(rep(List1,each = length(List2)),List2,sep = "_")
```

### Output

```
[1] "X_Enable"  "X_Status"  "X_Quality" "Y_Enable"  "Y_Status"  "Y_Quality" "Z_Enable"  "Z_Status"  "Z_Quality"
```

Answer (score 2):

We may use `outer`

```
c(outer(List1, List2, FUN = function(x, y) paste(x, y, sep = "_")))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `interaction` like below

```
> levels(interaction(List1, List2, sep = "_"))
[1] "X_Enable"  "Y_Enable"  "Z_Enable"  "X_Quality" "Y_Quality" "Z_Quality"
[7] "X_Status"  "Y_Status"  "Z_Status"
```

or `expand.grid`

```
> do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(List1, List2), sep = "_"))
[1] "X_Enable"  "Y_Enable"  "Z_Enable"  "X_Status"  "Y_Status"  "Z_Status"
[7] "X_Quality" "Y_Quality" "Z_Quality"
```